# Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas using Scala Driver

Tags: mongodb, scala

I'm having trouble connecting to a Mongo DB Atlas instance from my Scala application using the MongoDB Scala Driver

I get the error below when I try create a client (doing this from SBT Console)

```
scala> val url = "mongodb+srv://dbuser:dbpass@host.mongodb.net/test"
url: String = mongodb+srv://dbuser:dbpass@host.mongodb.net/test
scala> val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(url)
Apr 15, 2018 8:02:55 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[dbname-shard-00-00-randomchars.mongodb.net:27017, dbname-shard-00-01-randomchars.mongodb.net:27017, dbname-shard-00-02-randomchars.mongodb.net:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500, requiredReplicaSetName='dbname-shard-randomchars
Apr 15, 2018 8:02:55 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server dbname-shard-00-00-randomchars.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
Apr 15, 2018 8:02:55 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server dbname-shard-00-01-randomchars.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
Apr 15, 2018 8:02:55 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server dbname-shard-00-02-randomchars.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
mongoClient: org.mongodb.scala.MongoClient = MongoClient(com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientImpl@50416ab3)

scala> Apr 15, 2018 8:02:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server host.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponent(ZLio/netty/buffer/ByteBuf;)Lio/netty/buffer/CompositeByteBuf;
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:136)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponent(ZLio/netty/buffer/ByteBuf;)Lio/netty/buffer/CompositeByteBuf;
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.writeAsync(NettyStream.java:182)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.write(NettyStream.java:167)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:403)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:270)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:253)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:34)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:91)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:51)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    ... 2 more
```

After a while, I also get this output repeatedly on the console:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

This is my first time doing this, and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I have tested the endpoints + credentials using both the MongoDB CLI & Mongo DB Compass (GUI) and they're both working fine.

Additional info:

```
OS Version: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

MongoDB Atlas version: Version 3.4.14
Mongo DB Scala Driver Version: 2.2
Scala Version: 2.12.5
```

Here's my `build.sbt` file (simple from scala-seed project):

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.5",
      version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    )),
    name := "Hello",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      scalaTest % Test,
      "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.2.1",
      "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.0.4.Final"
    )
  )
```

I have also temporarily allowed access from any IP on MongoDB Atlas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of netty installed on the classPath is missing: `CompositeByteBuf.addComponent(ByteBuf)` and thats the cause of the `NoSuchMethodError`.

The version required by the Mongo Scala Driver in the [pom](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/scala/mongo-scala-driver_2.12/2.2.1/mongo-scala-driver_2.12-2.2.1.pom) is netty 4.1.17.Final - so please ensure that is on the classPath and can be used by the Scala driver.

Comment: I added this to my `build.sbt`'s libraryDependencies: `"io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.1.17.Final"`